# Multinomial Logistic Regression in spark ml vs mllib

Tags: apache-spark, machine-learning

Spark Version 2.0.0  has the stated goal to bring feature parity between the `ml` and the now-deprecated `mllib` packages.

Presently however the `ml` package provides ElasticNet support but only with binary regression.  To obtain multinomial apparently we have to accept using the deprecated mllib?

The downsides of using mllib:

- It is deprecated. So we will have the "why are you using the old stuff" questions to field
- They do not use the `ml` workflow so it does not integrate cleanly
- For the above reasons we would eventually have to do a rewrite.

Is there an approach available to achieving the one-vs-all multinomial with the `ml` package?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an answer-in-progress.  There *is* a `OneVsRest` classifier in `spark.ml`.
Apparently the approach is to provide the `LogisticRegressionClassifier` as a binary classifier to it - which will run the binary version across all classes and return the class with the highest score.

**Update** in response to @zero323.  Here is the info from `Xiangrui Meng` on the deprecation of mllib:

> Switch RDD-based MLlib APIs to maintenance mode in Spark 2.0

```
Hi all,

More than a year ago, in Spark 1.2 we introduced the ML pipeline API built on top of Spark SQL’s DataFrames. Since then the new DataFrame-based API has been developed under the spark.ml package, while the old RDD-based API has been developed in parallel under the spark.mllib package. While it was easier to implement and experiment with new APIs under a new package, it became harder and harder to maintain as both packages grew bigger and bigger. And new users are often confused by having two sets of APIs with overlapped functions.

We started to recommend the DataFrame-based API over the RDD-based API in Spark 1.5 for its versatility and flexibility, and we saw the development and the usage gradually shifting to the DataFrame-based API. Just counting the lines of Scala code, from 1.5 to the current master we added ~10000 lines to the DataFrame-based API while ~700 to the RDD-based API. So, to gather more resources on the development of the DataFrame-based API and to help users migrate over sooner, I want to propose switching RDD-based MLlib APIs to maintenance mode in Spark 2.0. What does it mean exactly?

* We do not accept new features in the RDD-based spark.mllib package, unless they block implementing new features in the DataFrame-based spark.ml package.
* We still accept bug fixes in the RDD-based API.
* We will add more features to the DataFrame-based API in the 2.x series to reach feature parity with the RDD-based API.
* Once we reach feature parity (possibly in Spark 2.2), we will deprecate the RDD-based API.
* We will remove the RDD-based API from the main Spark repo in Spark 3.0.

Though the RDD-based API is already in de facto maintenance mode, this announcement will make it clear and hence important to both MLlib developers and users. So we’d greatly appreciate your feedback!

(As a side note, people sometimes use “Spark ML” to refer to the DataFrame-based API or even the entire MLlib component. This also causes confusion. To be clear, “Spark ML” is not an official name and there are no plans to rename MLlib to “Spark ML” at this time.)

Best,
Xiangrui
```

**Another Update** There is a **JIRA** for this and the work is nearing completion as of May 2016  [Support multiclass logistic regression in spark.ml](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7159)

Comment: @zero323  Yes thanks I saw your answer there .   I am cloning `ml.LogisticRegression` because we have a custom optimizer. The `ml` logic bakes in (i.e. `private`) as either `breeze.linalg.LBFGS` or `OWLQN` - with the discriminator being `(elasticnet==0 or regparam ==0)` .

Comment: Thanks. BTW what is the source of the information about `mllib` being deprecated? I've seen a few individual classes (different regression variants) marked as deprecated but nothing more.

Comment: @zero323  Deprecation of `mllib` happened one or two releases ago. The stated goal for 2.0.0 is to achieve feature parity - so that the deprecation stops being a catch-22.  In terms of "sources" for the info it has been out there on the dev mailing list and I believe blogs as well. I can look it up.

Comment: @zero323 I have added the info about `mllib deprecation` to the WIP answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Sadly I can upvote only once :) Though I have to say it is quite disappointing.

Comment: @zero323  A related question is - will they deprecate `DataFrame` in favor of `DataSet`.    I guess it keeps us on our toes.

Comment: @zero323 Apologies for opening up this thread with new comment, but does One_vs_all support getting the feature weights? Like my doubt is if we have 3 class, then we have three underlying logistic regression. To predict the class of an example, all three are run and the one which gives the highest prob for a class is chosen as that example's class. So then that means for each example we do this. So there is no one common weight vector from a model which we can use to get a sense of features which are important? There are three weight vectors then. Is this even possible to get a common weight